# Django Rest Framework POST not saving to database Products ERROR: User already exists

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addProduct(request):
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data = request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        print("valid!!!")
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Above is my views.py for adding a product.

Below is my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from products.models import Product
from userProfile.serializers import UserSerializer

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
```

Below is my `Product` model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_of_purchase = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    defects = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.uuid)
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product_name}"
```

`UserSerializer` used in `ProductSerializer`

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name','email','date_joined','is_staff','is_active']
```

My input:

```json
{
    "id": 4,
    "user": {
        "username": "Anirudh",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "email@email.com",
        "date_joined": "2023-06-15T15:15:57.138400Z",
        "is_staff": true,
        "is_active": true
    },
    "uuid": "qwerty",
    "product_name": "Phone",
    "model": "iPhone 12 mini 64GB",
    "date_of_purchase": "2021-08-15",
    "description": "Working condition, no dents. all buttons work. Upgrading to new phone so I am selling",
    "defects": "None",
    "price": 20000,
    "slug": "qwerty"
}
```

I am getting an error stating that user already exists with this username.
I am able to create products from the same user from django admin panel but not able to create using DRF. The `if serializer.is_valid():` is false when I `POST` data

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default. So you need to write your own. Also, the `id` in your payload is irrelevant since you are creating new objects.

One possible option is in your `view` remove `user` from `request.data` and pass it as an [extra context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to `ProductSerializer`. There, we override `.create` and use this data to check if an `User` exists if not we create one.

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addProduct(request):
    user = request.data.pop('user')
    serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data, context={'user': user})
    
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        print("valid!!!")
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {"user": {"required": False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = self.context.get("user", None)
        try:
            user_instance = User.objects.get(username=user_data["username"])
            validated_data["user"] = user_instance
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                user_instance = serializer.save()
                validated_data["user"] = user_instance

        return super().create(validated_data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)

        user_id = representation.pop("user")
        user_instance = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user_instance)
        representation["user"] = serializer.data
        return representation
```

Overriding `.to_representation` is optional, I did it to obtain the response in the same format as the payload, otherwise it returns only user `id`.